# Why onCreate method doesn't execute next lines after getting location with Google Play services location APIs?

Tags: android, android-activity, geolocation, oncreate

In my `onCreate` method `getLocation()` method gets information using the Google Play services location APIs. It works well, but after executing `getLocation()` my `onCreate` method **doesn't execute next lines of code.** What shoud I do to execute next lines in my `onCreate` method after finishing with `getLocation()`? Thanks!

```
    public class WeatherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    TextView locationTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather);
        locationTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationTextView);
        getLocation();

        //Next line doesn't execute 
        locationTextView.setText("THIS TEXT WILL NEVER APPEAR");
    }

    private void getLocation() {
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if (location != null) {
                            //Setting text to TextView
                            locationTextView.setText("THIS TEXT IS OK");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something else after you `getLocation()` call inside onCreate? For instance a `Log.d("WeatherActivity", "Your log")` or even placing a breakpoint? Maybe the textview doesn't display the text because it's too fast and show almost immediately your text provided by your OnSuccess callback.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line doesn't execute or it just doesn't behave as you expect? Did you put a breakpoint there and debug it?

To me it seems that the line executes fine but the text gets quickly overriden by `onSuccess` callback.

`onSuccess` doesn't get called immediatelly but some time in the future. So it's very likely that the line `locationTextView.setText("THIS TEXT WILL NEVER APPEAR");` gets executed before the code in `onSuccess`

Answer (score 0):

You must move `locationTextView.setText("THIS TEXT WILL NEVER APPEAR");` to another method because as soon as onCreate method executes activity cycle's next method executes i.e onSuccess()